# Keep a div above the fold when resizing

Tags: html, css

I want to have

```
            <li><span class="number">01</span>
            <h3><a href="#/twocomputers" style="letter-spacing: 1px;">Two Computers</a></h3>
            </li>
```

above the fold even when resizing. Right now, it'll only appear when the browser is tall vertically but when you shrink it down, it just moves down.

http://jsfiddle.net/j05rpbam/

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`.

If you set the position of the element to `fixed`, it's fixed on screen, so if the css is

```
#myDiv
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 200px;
}
```

Then `#myDiv` would always be 10px from the top of the screen and 200px from the left. `position: absolute` works similarly, but is relative to the document body and/or the parent of the element, and therefore is affected by scrolling, which doesn't seem like what you want.